# Status bar turns transparent while scrolling SliverAppBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sliverappbar

- I am using `SliverAppBar` to scroll the appbar when content scrolls in my `flutter` app but as soon as I scroll the list statusbar color turns transparent.
- I want statusbar in its place and with the default primary color which is blue in my case.
- See: [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sqRquq5IKqHQ-CB3hahUccYuhSsgaRyP/view?usp=sharing)

> Here is code:

```
Scaffold(
    CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("Home"),
            floating: false,
            pinned: false,
            snap: false,
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(SOME_LIST_DATA),
          ),
        ],
      )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand the color of the status bar is changed automatically depending on the AppBar Brightness see: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html.

But if as i suspect what you want to achieve is to keep the status bar the default color of your AppBar you can do this (although i don't particularly recommend it):

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor));
```

Of course you can change the `Theme.of(context).primaryColor` by any color you wish.

Comment: From the link I provided: « Call this API in code whose lifecycle matches that of the desired system UI styles. For instance, to change the system UI style on a new page, consider calling when pushing/popping a new PageRoute. »

Answer (score 0):

wrap your widget with SafeArea, it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Use SafeArea. It's easy and convenient.
Below is the official doc link.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html